# How to save data in a one to zero or one relationship with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have two tables that have a relationship of one to zero or one, `InvoiceSale` and `Budget`. A sales invoice can have a `Budget` (or not), but every `Budget` belongs to exactly one sales invoice.

This is my `InvoiceSale` class:

```
public class InvoiceSale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public int NumberInvoice { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceSaleDate { get; set; }
    public Budget Budget{ get; set; }
}
```

And this is my `Budget` class:

```
public class Budget
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte StateId { get; set; }
    public long Total { get; set; }
    public InvoiceSale InvoiceSale { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my fluent API configuration of the relationship:

```
HasOptional(fv => fv.Budget)
   .WithOptionalDependent(p => p.InvoiceSale)
   .Map(m => m.MapKey("BudgetId")); //I don't have a navigation property for 
    //this
```

When I send data from a form, I send the `BudgetId` value of a drop-down list, but when I try to save the changes in Entity Framework, the `BudgetId` which is an optional field always inserts null.

Since I do not have a navigation property for `BudgetId`, I don't know how to send this value to the database with Entity Framework.

Here is the controller action that inserts the data:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateInvoiceSale(InvoiceSale newInvoiceSale)
{
    var invoiceSale = new InvoiceSale
    {                    
        NumberInvoice = newInvoiceSale.NumberInvoice ,
        InvoiceSaleDate = newInvoiceSale.InvoiceSaleDate ,
        // Here I need to pass the BudgetId value, but how can I do it 
        // without a navigation property?
    };

    _context.InvoiceSales.Add(invoiceSale);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Json("ok"):
}
```

Comment: `public Budget Budget{ get; set; }` is not this a navigation property? you will need either to create the `Budget` instance first or fetch it from db.

Comment: are you receiving budget id value from View?

Comment: Yes, is a value from a drop down list.

Comment: I have added answer with updated your code.

Comment: Let me know if it works or not.